# Switching between multiple Fragments hosted by an Activity using callbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have an Activity  that can switch between two fragments by implementing their Callbacks interface, like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ListFragment.Callbacks, MyFragment.Callbacks {
override fun onMyFragmentSelected() {
        val fragment = MyFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }

override fun onListFragmentSelected() {
        val fragment = ListFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

Fragment class:

```
private var callbacks: Callbacks?=null

interface Callbacks {
    fun onListFragmentSelected()
}
//On button press i call this to switch to ListFragment
callbacks?.onListFragmentSelected()
```

I want to add several new Fragments and introduce a toolbar menu in all of them, which can be used to switch from any X fragment to any Y fragment. But I can't put for example onListFragmentSelected() in two different Fragments and override both of them in MainActivity because the two have the same name. Can I somehow take this logic outside of the Fragments or do I have to name each function uniquely (I feel like this would be very messy)

Comment: I'd recommend using the navigation component which would make all this a lot easier: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into the [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) component for this too, it has a lot of stuff built already that handles things like menus and navigation commands. But if you want to do this yourself, here's some ideas!

If this is a toolbar that's in every fragment, I feel like these callbacks have nothing to do with the fragments *themselves*. It's the menu that decides what options it displays, and it's the `Activity` that provides the ability to navigate to certain fragments. To me, this feels more like an interface associated with the *menu* - defining a way for it to communicate with a component that will handle navigation etc.

So to do things that way, you could have a `MenuCallbacks` interface:

```
interface MenuCallbacks {
    fun navigateToMyFragment()
    fun navigateToListFragment()
    // etc
}
```

and then make your `Activity` implement that.

This way, it's your *menu* that's defining all the callback names, and you're forced to use a unique name for each method. Which makes sense, because you need to be explicit about where you're going! If you have two different `Fragment`s that want to call their navigation method `onListFragmentSelected`, then you have a problem (besides the name collision) because that's ambiguous. This is part of the reason you want the coordinator controlling this kind of thing, not the things being coordinated.

---

Another approach, instead of an interface with a function named after each `Fragment`, is to just use the `Fragment`'s *class* itself:

```
// in your Activity
fun navigateTo(fragmentClass: Class<Fragment>) {
    val fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance()
    ...
}

// from your menu
activity.navigateTo(MyFragment::class.java)
```

This way, instead of having to have a special function for each `Fragment`, you can just pass the class for the one you want to navigate to. And there's absolutely no ambiguity possible there - the `Fragment` whose class you pass is the one you get!

In fact, using the *class* is [the recommended way of adding fragments in a transaction](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#add-remove) anyway, because it lets the system handle the creation and recreation as needed:

```
fun navigateTo(fragmentClass: Class<Fragment>) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentClass, null) // last param is constructor args
        ...
}
```

---

Since that last approach allows you to pass in *any* `Fragment` class, and you might want to limit it to a fixed set (like the interface does), you might want to define a type that represents the `Fragment`s that are allowed. You could do this with an enum:

```
enum class MenuDestination(val fragmentClass: Class<Fragment>) {
    MY_FRAGMENT(MyFragment::class.java)
    LIST_FRAGMENT(ListFragment::class.java)
}
```

And then your navigation function just needs to take a parameter of that type instead:

```
fun navigateTo(destination: MenuDestination) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, destination.fragmentClass, null)
        ...
}
```

I'd associate that enum with your *menu* (e.g. nest inside a `Menu` class that represents the menu, or whatever you're using for it, a `Fragment` maybe) since the enum defines possible destinations, and that's also what your menu does. You could even expand that enum with properties like the IDs of drawables and string labels for each item, and basically populate the menu itself from the `values()` in that enum - that way it's all defined in a single place!